# Сократить однотипный код

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Все изумительно работает , но можно как то оптимизировать подобный код ?
Знаний JS не достаточно , а таких скриптов штук 20 на странице(
И кажутся громоздкими...

```js
function smena(){
    document.getElementById('1_1').src='1.png';
    document.getElementById('1_2').src='2.png';
    document.getElementById('1_3').src='3.png';
    document.getElementById('1_4').src='4.png';
    document.getElementById('1_5').src='5.png';
    document.getElementById('1_6').className = "";
    document.getElementById('1_7').className = "";
    document.getElementById('1_8').className = "";
    document.getElementById('1_9').className = "";
    document.getElementById('1_10').className = "";
    document.getElementById('1_11').className = "active";
    document.getElementById('1_12').className = "";
    document.getElementById('1_13').className = "";
    document.getElementById('1_14').className = "";
    document.getElementById('1_15').className = "";
    document.getElementById('1_16').className = "";
    document.getElementById('1_17').className = "";
    document.getElementById('1_18').className = "";
    document.getElementById('1_19').className = "";
    document.querySelector('[name="1_20"]').selectedIndex=6;
}
```

Comment: Действительно, так нельзя. Но без контекста, оптимизация невозможна.

Comment: Ну и почитайте про циклы, конечно же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рефакторить этот код(подставлять id в цикле), как есть, думаю смысла нет, они тут от фонаря.

Как вариант рефакторинга, можно растащить эти часто необходимые действия по отдельным функциям:

```
var Util = function(){
  return {setImgs, toggleUniqueClass, selectChange};

  // выставляет элементам с id соответствующий src
  function setImgs(map) {
    for (let id in map) {
      document.getElementById(id).src = map[id];
    }
  }

  // убирает класс из всех элементов, кроме одного
  function toggleUniqueClass(ids, activeId, className) {
    ids.forEach(id => document.getElementById(id).classList.remove(className));
    document.getElementById(activeId).classList.add(className);
  }

  // выбирает элемент index в списке с именем name
  function selectChange(name, index) {
    document.querySelector('[name="'+name+'"]').selectedIndex = sel.index
  }
}();


function smena(){
  Util.setImgs({'1_1': '1.png', '1_2': '2.png'/*...*/});
  Util.toggleUniqueClass(['1_6', '1_7', '1_8'/*...*/], '1_8', 'active');
  Util.selectChange('1_20', 6);
}
```

Comment: в чем смысл делать Util функцией?

Comment: Привычка... Типа статический класс)